# Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectType); doesn't work with custom objects

Tags: apex, sobject, schema, describesobject, sobjectfield

I have a method that returns a map of all the fields where the field's API name is the key and the object Schema.SObjectField is the value.

```
    private static Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap(String objectType){
         Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
         Schema.SObjectType objectSchema = schemaMap.get(objectType);
         Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objectSchema?.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
         return fieldMap;
    }
```

It works well with standard objects but it won't with custom objects.
The line
`Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objectSchema?.getDescribe().fields.getMap();` throws the error `Attempt to de-reference a null object`.

Any idea why? The Object's API Name is *CO_Shuttle__c*.

Thank you,

Comment: Does this happen in the org that you initially created the custom SObject in? Or is it happening in an org that you deployed this custom SObject to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your object part of a managed package? If so, you may need to deal with the namespace as well.

```
Map<String, sObjectField> mapping = fieldMap('myNs__CO_Shuttle__c');
```

You can avoid a lot of this hassle by using an `sObjectType` token if you have it:

```
static Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap(sObjectType token) {
  return token?.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
}
```

But at that point, it's a one-liner; you can just use this directly.

```
Map<String, sObjectField> fieldMap = sObjectType.CO_Shuttle__c.fields.getMap();
```

Note that using a token guarantees you will find the sObjectType or you'll get a compilation error. Always prefer to use hard-coded tokens whenever possible.

If you absolutely need it to be dynamic, you can also use `Type.forName`:

```
static Map<String, sObjectField> fieldMap(String objectApiName);
  Type sType = Type.forName('Schema', objectApiName);
  if(sType == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException('Unable to find '+objectApiName);
  }
  sObject template = (sObject)sType.newInstance();
  sObjectType sType = template.getSobjectType();
  return sType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
}
```

I would strongly advise against using your method as written, as `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` is very expensive in CPU time, and may even time out in large orgs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I The object isn't part of a managed package, and I would need it to be dynamic indeed... I tried the method with ```Type.forName``` but I get the following error ```IllegalArgumentException:[]: Unable to find CO_Shuttle_c```. The problem seems to be that Schema can't access custom objects for some reason...

Comment: Your previous comment suggests a typo. It would end "__c" not "_c".

Comment: If the object is not part of a managed package, why does your question show `myNs.CO_Shuttle__c` (I.e. with an attempt to add a namespace prefix)? If it needs a namespace, the correct form is `myNs__CO_Shuttle__c`.

Comment: @PhilW Haha, yeah, sorry. I'll edit that.

Comment: @Jean As Phil mentioned, looks like you have a typo: it's `__c`, not `_c`. Very common mistake to make if you're not paying attention or new to Salesforce. We've all done it at least once. 

Comment: Thanks everybody, that was it indeed...